# Why INotifyPropertyChanged on Model is not reflected immediately in View?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I am having problems with property bindings in Winform in simple MVVM architecture. Both view model and model have implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I have two properties `a` and `b` bound to textboxes. Property `b` is in view model and is changed by method in ViewModel in response to button and this is working fine. Accordingly, property `a` is in model and is changed by a method in model. In view model there is a property changed listener from model in order to notify view about `a`.

And binding of the `a` property is not working as expected. Each button click increments `a` in the model, `Model_PropertyChanged` is fired with proper property name of `a`, but textbox does not update. Textbox with `a` updates only if property `b` is changed in view model...

What am I missing here?

Code behind of Form:

```
public partial class TestPropertyChangedForm : Form
{
    TestPropertyChangedVM VM;

    public TestPropertyChangedForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VM = new TestPropertyChangedVM();

        tbModel.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), VM, nameof(VM.a));
        tbViewModel.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), VM, nameof(VM.b));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VM.CmdIncrementA(); 
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VM.CmdIncrementB();
    }
}
```

View model code:

```
public class TestPropertyChangedVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    TestPropertyChanged Model;

    public TestPropertyChangedVM()
    {
        Model = new TestPropertyChanged();
        Model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(e.PropertyName));
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int a
    { 
        get { return Model.a; }
        set { Model.a = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int _b;

    public int b
    { 
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void CmdIncrementA()
    {
        Model.CmdIncrementA();
    }

    public void CmdIncrementB()
    {
        b++;
    }
}
```

Model :

```
public class TestPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int _a;

    public int a 
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void CmdIncrementA()
    {
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're binding to `TestPropertyChangedVM.a` but you never change that property, you change `TestPropertyChanged.a` and so the NotifyPropertyChangedEvent will be incorrect for the binding. BTW you're treating `TestPropertyChanged` as a ViewModel

Comment: But `TestPropertyChangedVM.a` value is actually defined as `TestPropertyChanged.a` through getter and setter, as you can see in VM code. So, if my understanding is correct, View should treat PropertyChanged event with property name `a` as it was property of VM and should read actual value of `VM.a`, which in reality will be `Model.a`.